# does mod_rewrite on file extensions interfere with verification files?

Tags: html, url, mod-rewrite, google-apps, pinterest

I'm currently using `mod_rewrite` to remove the `.HTML` extension from files, as well as redirect to their friendly versions.

I use the `pinterest.html` and `google.html` files for verifying my Pinterest page and Google Apps account.

For mod_rewrite, I am using this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

My question is about the logic and function of it in relation to the verification files. The purpose as I understand is to serve `'x' file` with `'y' URL`.

So even though I am serving `example.com/pinterest.html` as `example.com/pinterest` due to the redirection and `.HTML` removal, there shouldn't be any interference since the file is still readable as always, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rewrite the two special files.  Add a negative assertion to the cond regexp:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(?!pinterest\.html|google\.html).*\.html\ HTTP/
```

PS. why not just match `%{REQUEST_URI}`  ?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(pinterest|google)\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
```

I've rewritten this in simple regexp.  What this says is don't match the two special files but so match any other request for a `.html` file.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, and I'm not very familiar with mod_rewrite, it's just code I used from another stackoverflow question's answer. Mind if I ask something else? In the cond, what is the purpose of `HTTP/` at the end? And what specifically would be the difference if I switched to URI from FILENAME?

Comment: Thanks again. Tried some different combinations, only got the following to work:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(?!pinterest\.html|google\.html).*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

I was reading the differences on apache.org between `REQUEST_URI`, `REQUEST_FILENAME`, and `THE_REQUEST`. `REQUEST_URI` seems like the best, but I'm not sure how to implement it. What can I change in the rewrite above for best performance?

Comment: The `REQUEST_URI` includes query parameters so if you don't use them this is the same as the `REQUEST_FILENAME`.  So if you use them either drop the `$` anchor to the end of string or use the FILENAME variant.